# VSCode Error involving; Debugging Swift file, missing 'host' platform architecture

Tags: json, swift, architecture, lldb, vscode-debugger

I've run into this problem while trying to run a simple swift file in VSCode. After setting up the JSON folder, the app says that it cannot run the file because it does not contain any 'host' platform architecture (the word host is in quotes). It is then followed by a long list of what I assume are architectures such as arm64 and x86_64. I am newer to programming so I am unfamiliar with these terms.

Right now my JSON code is :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.swift",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also have the extensions CodeLLDB by Vadim Chugunov and Swift by Swift Server Work Group. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this in VScode Id be very appreciative. The debugger works in Xcode, but I prefer not to use that app if able.

Comment: It looks like you are setting your executable (the "program" argument) to your .swift file.  That should be the binary, not the swift source file, since you are telling lldb to run it.  It seems odd that you would have to specify the binary location - presumably VSCode already knows that since it's building it for you?  You might try leaving out the program argument and see if VSCode gets it right?  Otherwise, try finding where the binary is in your workspace (unless you renamed it it will be called just `main`) and specify that path instead and see if that works better.